# Minor spacing in integer factorization

Tags: c++

I have to factor a number into its multiplicatives, each one separated by `*` (multiplicative sign). However, when a number is fully multiplied (i.e., has no more multiples) there is expected to be a space instead of a `*`. I have done most of the program but the spacing messes me up and gives me a bad answer that has one extra answer in each "set" than necessary (this will be displayed after the code). Any solutions/suggestions? (I am aware that my code forces me to add `*` after every single number, however, I'm not sure how to make it so that it won't add another).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
 long int a, numb, mult;
 cin>>a;
 for (int i=0; i<a; i++)
 {
     cin>>numb;
     int mult =2;
      do{
         if (numb%mult==0)
         {numb/=mult;
          cout<<mult<<"*";
          mult=2; }//reset to two everytime it works
         else
         mult++;
         if (mult==numb)
         {cout<<" ";}
        } while (mult<numb+1);
  }
}
```

Input:

```
24
748931598137
466275117851
1314968912503
22379700293
1447643167643
1661926271899
2791977129181
1011164951317
654894646933
5597103144649
3057631770959
1161087606193
20104997131
834666701749
1609453631861
6967357950821
672835916659
1836903165421
1249178869333
858443597863
509391258631
1046982843367
2449157951257
1207036282367
```

Output:

```
109*137*277*331* 547*61*71*431*439* 569*113*197*239*439* 563*181*421*509* 577*53*241*431*439* 599*127*199*271*431* 563*97*241*449*461* 577*163*223*229*331* 367*83*107*307*401* 599*281*313*317*367* 547*193*223*257*491* 563*101*181*311*443* 461*197*347*491* 599*137*211*257*283* 397*127*233*271*419* 479*223*331*389*431* 563*107*157*283*307* 461*107*281*331*379* 487*197*233*233*271* 431*101*239*271*281* 467*61*73*353*541* 599*157*211*223*239* 593*79*283*431*433* 587*67*257*349*353* 569*
```

Expected:

```
109*137*277*331*547 61*71*431*439*569 113*197*239*439*563 181*421*509*577 53*241*431*439*599 127*199*271*431*563 97*241*449*461*577 163*223*229*331*367 83*107*307*401*599 281*313*317*367*547 193*223*257*491*563 101*181*311*443*461 197*347*491*599 137*211*257*283*397 127*233*271*419*479 223*331*389*431*563 107*157*283*307*461 107*281*331*379*487 197*233*233*271*431 101*239*271*281*467 61*73*353*541*599 157*211*223*239*593 79*283*431*433*587 67*257*349*353*569
```

Alternative program with blank output:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
 long int a, numb, mult;
 bool prime = false;
 cin>>a;
 for (int i=0; i<a; i++)
 {
     cin>>numb;
     int mult;
      do{mult=2;
         if (numb%mult==0)
         {numb/=mult;
          cout<<mult;
          mult=2;       //reset to two everytime it works
             prime= true;    } 
         else
         mult++;
         if (prime==true)
         {
             for (int mult=2; mult<numb+1; mult++)
             {if (numb%mult==0) //can it be further multiplied?
             cout<<"*"; 
             break;} //we're just testing for one time
         }
         if (mult==numb)
         {cout<<" ";}
        } while (mult<numb+1);
  }
}
```

Comment: You could write to a `std::stringstream` instead of `cout`, and then grab a substring up to but not including the last character.

Comment: OT: `mult=2; //reset to two everytime it works` is silly. If you have just figured out that 17 is the smallest factor and then you divide the number by 17, that will not create any new factors smaller than 17 (or, for that matter, larger than 17). So there's no point trying all those numbers again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up with after cleaning up your code a little bit.
The key is to just check if you are done factoring your number before you print out the `'*'` character.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    long int a, numb, mult;
    cin>>a;
    for (int i=0; i<a; i++)
    {
        cin>>numb;
        int mult =2;
        do{
            if (numb % mult == 0)
            {
                numb /= mult;
                cout << mult;
                if(numb == 1)
                    cout << ' ';
                else
                    cout << '*';
            }
            else
                mult++;
        } while (numb != 1);
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```

Example:
Input: `3 5000 4999 4998`
Output: `2*2*2*5*5*5*5 4999 2*3*7*7*17`